# react native : How can I arrange the items one to three in a row and everything from four in a separate row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I arrange the items one to three in a row and everything from four in a separate row?
i add picture of what i want achieve :

[image: picture]

```
const filter_radio_props = [
  { label: 'one', value: 0 },
  { label: 'two', value: 1 },
  { label: 'three', value: 2 },
  { label: 'four', value: 3 },
  { label: 'five', value: 4 },
  { label: 'six', value: 5 },
  { label: 'seven', value: 6 },
  { label: 'eight', value: 7 },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { View, Text, FlatList, CheckBox, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
const filter_radio_props = [
  { label: 'one', value: 0 },
  { label: 'two', value: 1 },
  { label: 'three', value: 2 },
  { label: 'four', value: 3 },
  { label: 'five', value: 4 },
  { label: 'six', value: 5 },
  { label: 'seven', value: 6 },
  { label: 'eight', value: 7 },
];

let data = [];

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = React.useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
  const [FilterModalVisible, setFilterModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const getData = () => {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filter_radio_props.length; i += 3) {
      data.push(filter_radio_props.slice(i, i + 3));
      console.log(filter_radio_props.slice(i, i + 3));
    }
    // console.log(data);
    if (data[data.length - 1].length !== 3) {
      if (data.length == 1) {
        data.[data.length-1].push({});
        data.[data.length-1].push({});
      } else {
        data.[data.length-1].push({});
      }
    }
    return data;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [FilterModalVisible]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Searchbar
        style={{ marginTop: 60 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={(query) => {
          setFirstQuery(query);
        }}
        value={firstQuery}
        icon="arrow-right"
        onIconPress={() => {
          setFilterModalVisible(!FilterModalVisible);
        }}
      />
      <Text>
        {' '}
        FilterModalVisible {FilterModalVisible ? ' : True' : ' : False'}
      </Text>
      {getData().map((d) => (
        <FlatList
          data={d.reverse()}
          numColumns={3}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
           <View style={[styles.itemView, !item.label?{backgroundColor: ""}:null]}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item.label}</Text>
            </View>}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemView: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    margin: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

export default MyComponent;
```

[Expo Snack Link](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/carefree-cookie)

Comment: i mean only to downline in three part ..like /n

Comment: You can also try using ```react-native-gridview```: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gridview 
I hope the given example answers your question or at least gives you an idea about how you can approach the problem. 
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

in flatlets you have access to index, you can check if index is less than 3, then apply a different style (in this case width = 33.33%)

```
 <FlatList
        data={filter_radio_props.slice(3)}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return index < 3 ? 
          <View style={styles.threeColumn}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.label}</Text>
            <CheckBox value={item.value}/>
          </View>
          :
          <View style={styles.itemView}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.label}</Text>
            <CheckBox value={item.value}/>
          </View>
        }}
      />


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemView: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    margin: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text:{
    color: "white"
  },
  threeColumn: {
    width: '33.33%'
  }
});
```